# Output per fragment data through SSBO

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I need to output 24 indices per fragment in a shader. I already reached the maximum amount of rendertargets because I'm using four other rendertargets for my gbuffer. So I tried to output the data with an SSBO, indexing it with the gl_FragCoord of the pixel. The problem is, that it needs to be depth correct. So I tried to use `layout(early_fragment_tests) in;` and watched over the indices. I can see strange per pixel errors on some spots now and it looks like the indices from the triangles below are coming through plus it stops when I'm moving the camera closer to those spots. 
I double checked the indexing of the ssbo and it's correct + the indices should be the same for a whole triangle, but the flickering is per pixel. So I think the depth test works only for the rasterized per pixel output and not for the whole fragment shader code. Could it be the problem or does somebody know if the depth test should stop the whole processing of the fragment? If that's not the case, even a separate depth pre pass couldn't help me.

Here is a fragment shader example:

```
#version 440 core

layout(early_fragment_tests) in;

layout(location = 0) uniform sampler2D texSampler;

#include "../Header/MaterialData.glslh"
#include "../Header/CameraUBO.glslh"

layout(location = 3) uniform uint screenWidth;//horizontal screen resolution in pixel

layout(location = 0) out vec4 fsout_color;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 fsout_normal;
layout(location = 2) out vec4 fsout_material;

coherent layout(std430, binding = 3) buffer frameCacheIndexBuffer
{
    uvec4 globalCachesIndices[];
};

in vec3 gsout_normal;
in vec2 gsout_texCoord;
flat in uvec4 gsout_cacheIndices[6];
flat in uint gsout_instanceIndex;

void main()
{
    uint frameBufferIndex = 6 * (uint(gl_FragCoord.x) + uint(gl_FragCoord.y) * screenWidth);
    for(uint i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        globalCachesIndices[frameBufferIndex + i] = gsout_cacheIndices[i];//only the closest fragment should output
    }

    fsout_normal = vec4(gsout_normal * 0.5f + 0.5f, 0);
    fsout_color = vec4(texture(texSampler, gsout_texCoord));

    MaterialData thisMaterial = material[materialIndex[gsout_instanceIndex]];

    fsout_material = vec4(thisMaterial.diffuseStrength, 
                        thisMaterial.specularStrength, 
                        thisMaterial.ambientStrength, 
                        thisMaterial.specularExponent);
}
```

Comment: Something's not right with your shader. I was trying to trace the computation of `frameBufferIndex` because I think you're overwriting the same index in the SSBO in multiple shader invocations, but `width` is undefined. I suspect it's in one of the files you used the `#include` directive on. Also, if you're doing this across multiple draw calls you probably need a memory barrier.

Comment: Oh, my fault, you are right it is in the camera include and stands for the horizontal screen resolution in pixel. I will add an explanation for the width variable. Overwriting the values was my first idea too but I double checked the frameBufferIndex  and it looked correct. Yes, I use glMemoryBarrier between my shader calls but its still flickering on some pixels.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by _"So I think the depth test works only for the rasterized per pixel output and not for the whole fragment shader code."_? The fragment shader only runs on rasterized fragments. Since the order your triangles are processed is not guaranteed to match the order they were drawn, you may write the same memory multiple times (even if you depth-sort) but early depth testing will make it so that the visible fragment is the last write. That behavior applies to triangles drawn in the same `glDraw*` call, to catch other order-dependent issues memory barriers are used.

Comment: With the rasterized output I mean the data which is going to be saved into the textures, like the color, the material and the normal. It would explain my error if only the rasterized per texture output is guarenteed to be depth correct. I mean, the gpu could still process the fragmen because of its parallel behaviour and only dump the per texture output if it's not the nearest depth value. I will check the barriers again to be sure that they work as expected. I'm also using glMultiDraw* maybe the glMemoryBarrier is not working between the shader invocations of those calls?

Comment: But even if that's the case, I already tested it with a single mesh and it's causing flickering too.

Comment: That's not how early fragment tests work. The depth test is executed before the fragment shader runs, so rather than "dumping the per-texture output" it the test fails it does not even run the shader. You actually *need* this behavior when you write to anything other than a framebuffer from a shader, because the normal merge behavior doesn't apply; there would be unpredictable side effects from fragments that were processed but discarded afterwards. _Can you explain how you're actually viewing the data in your SSBO? Are you reading it back from GL or processing it in another shader?_

Comment: Yes, I really hope that it works like this. For debugging I draw the indices in another shader per fragment. `perFragmentOutput = vec4(float(frameCacheIndices[index]) / 299.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);` where `index` is the per fragment index like in the shader example above and 299.0f is the maximum index. So I'm getting a single red tone per triangle on my single mesh, but on some parts the pixels in the triangles flickering with a different red tone. But I also think, if its the depth testing then I should get the background color there because I activated backface culling.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, but one thing that comes to mind is multisampling. Are you using multisampling? `gl_FragCoord` will generally be aligned to (x.5, y.5) when single-sampling, but with multisampling you can wind up with a coordinate that is off-center and that would certainly explain the flickering.

Comment: Nope no multisampling, but my statement about the depth testing and background color is wrong. The mesh is curved and the flickering is happening exactly there where another part of the mesh is behind. I also said one line after im setting the index that if the index isn't the same anymore the index should be zero. The result are black pixel at the flickering spots where the mesh has another part behind itself. So I think it must be the depth test which fails for the ssbo there. Here you can see the rotated mesh: [Mesh pictues](http://fs1.directupload.net/images/141127/5a49flqf.png)